# How can i put a variable in an awk command

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, variable, csv

with my code im trying to sum up the values with the specific name of a column in a csv file, depending on the input of the name.
Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

updatedata() {

    index=0
    while IFS="" read -r line
    do
        IFS=';' read -ra array <<< "$line"
        for arrpos in "${array[@]}"
        do
            if [ "$arrpos" == *"$1"* ] || [ "$1" == "$arrpos" ]
            then
                break
            else
                let index=index+1
            fi
        done
        break
       
    done < data.csv
    ((index=$index+1))


       
    if [ $pos -eq 0 ]
    then
        v0=$(awk -F";", -v index=$index '{x+=$index}END{print x}' ./data.csv )
    elif [ $pos -eq 1 ]
    then
        v1=$(awk -F";" '{x+=$index}END{print x}' ./data.csv )
    elif [ $pos -eq 2 ]
    then
        v2=$(awk -F";" '{x+=$index}END{print x}' ./data.csv )
    elif [ $pos -eq 3 ]
    then
        v3=$(awk -F";" '{x+=$index}END{print x}' ./data.csv )
    fi
               
                   
         
}
```

in the middle of code you can see in v0=, i was trying to experiment a little, but i just keep getting error.
First I tried this:

```
v0=$(awk -F";" '{x+=$index}END{print x}' ./data.csv)
```

but it gave me this error:
'awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }'

so then i decided to try this(as you can see in the code)

```
v0=$(awk -F";", -v index=$index '{x+=$index}END{print x}' ./data.csv )
```

And i got this error:
'awk: run time error: cannot command line assign to index
type clash or keyword
FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0'

i dont know what to do, can you guys help me

Comment: `index` is a built-in `awk` function. You may want to use another name for this variable (and use `$(varname)` in `awk`). You also should not have a comma after `-F ';'`. Not turning this into an answer as a real answer should probably also point to better ways of doing this operation (the shell loop is probably not needed).

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output then we could help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Given some CSV data in `data.csv`,

```
A;B;C
1;2;3
4;5;6
-1.2;3;3.3
```

the following script would calculate the sum of the column named by the `colname` variable given on the command line:

```c
BEGIN {
        FS = ";"

        if (colname == "") {
                print "Did not get column name (colname) to work with" >"/dev/stderr"
                exit 1
        }
}

FNR == 1 {
        colnum = 0

        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
                if ($i == colname) {
                        colnum = i
                        break
                }

        if (colnum == 0) {
                printf "Did not find named column (colname = \"%s\")\n", colname >"/dev/stderr"
                exit 1
        }

        sum = 0
        next
}

{
        sum += $colnum
}

END {
        print sum
}
```

Testing it:

```
$ awk -v colname='A' -f script.awk data.csv
3.8
$ awk -v colname='B' -f script.awk data.csv
10
$ awk -v colname='C' -f script.awk data.csv
12.3
$ awk -v colname='D' -f script.awk data.csv
Did not find named column (colname = "D")
```

---

Shorter variant of the script without so much error checking:

```c
BEGIN { FS = ";" }

FNR == 1 {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
                if ($i == colname) break

        if (i > NF) exit 1
        next
}

{ sum += $i }

END { print sum }
```

or, as a "one-liner":

```
$ awk -v colname='A' -F ';' 'FNR == 1 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == colname) break; if (i > NF) exit 1; next } { sum += $i } END { print sum }' data.csv
```

---

Ideally, though, you'd use some form of CSV parser, like CSVkit:

```
$ csvstat --sum -c A data.csv
3.8
```

The `csvstat` utility calculats several different statistics for any given CSV file.  Here, it figures out that the delimiter is `;` on its own.  In this example I ask it for the sum of the column named `A`.